# Stream Deck Using PI 2

Tags: pi-2, touchscreen, keyboard, python-3, hid

I have a RPi2 1gb. I've recently got a touch screen for it and have decided that I actually should use it for what it was intended for. Programming! So my adventure starts here.

I want to make a Stream Deck, now breaking down the already existing stream deck, It's basically a Macro Keyboard with a screen. Buttons press and it happens. From OBS to Posting twitter feeds.

Now I only have a Pi2 so I was wondering if it was possible to make it so that it talks over a network? Or at least get to the point where I can make it over to a PiZ to make it USB enabled.

I would like it to be to the point where I can customize the buttons a bit any stuff but I wanna get the basics done before I throw myself in the shark tank.

So Advice people!

Answer (score 0):

You have to break a project like this down to some general categories of constituent part and study those aspects independently rather than trying to accomplish a bunch of things that are new and unfamiliar to you in one project.  That will just waste a lot of time; in the beginning people tend to think the wrong way around, that just getting on with their ultimate goal is the fastest way to proceed.

By analogy, if we decide to go to LA from New York and you say, "Right, let's get on with it!", slip on some sandles, grab some change, and walk out the door thinking you will get there faster than if you learn to drive, save some money, order a ticket of some kind, etc., you are *probably* wrong and even if you do make in a decent amount of time -- say, hitchhiking -- you will eventually realise hitchhiking is not a reliable way to get around large parts of North America and anyone who does it regularly has invested in some alternate strategies.

The thing which jumps out here is *GUI programming*.  Choose a language, choose a [widget toolkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widget_toolkit) (e.g., Gtk+), and go through some tutorials.

---

Your Pi specific questions are really a hodgepodge of tangentially related things, if you need more details you should drill down on them individually.

> Can I make a Pi2 talk over a network?

Yes, although if you mean *wireless* network you would need a wifi adapter for it.

I presume you already know this, and what you really meant is *how*.  This the realm of *network programming*, and if you don't know anything about it, you will have to put in some time.

> can utilise my PI2 as a HID

Not directly in the way that the Zero can.

> is it possible to do this using a USB to TTL Serial Cable?

Sure, although again I suspect what you meant is *how*. The short answer to which is connect each pi's TX to the other's RX (actually, that doesn't involve a USB to TTL cable, it's just two wires), and use whatever UART software you want -- `minicom`, `miniterm.py`, etc. You will have to write your own code to do what you want; the advantage of this is that it is considerably simpler than IP networking.

Comment: I think where I'm trying to get to, is finding a way of making it so I can utilise my PI2 as a HID with my Raspberry PI Touch screen where is acts like a macro keyboard. Is there a GPIO hat that can be used to make it into a HID or a way or rigging up the PI-Z to my RPI Touch Screen? Or is it possible to do this using a USB to TTL Serial Cable?

Comment: Right, but the touchscreen interface is a GUI.  I imagine you can find virtual keyboard libraries around to simplify that.  However, the place to ask about that stuff though is our larger parent site, [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/).   For your other questions see above.

Comment: I'll refer you to this: https://makerhacks.com/graphical-pizero-stream-deck - This is basically what I wish to do. And is it possible to use the USB to TTL to do this?

Comment: I don't see why not, the biggest difference w/ the Pi 2 is you can't use the USB in slave mode -- **which is kind of a big difference,** if by "use the USB to TTL" what you mean is, plug the Pi 2 into a normal computer via a USB to TTL cable and have it act as a HID device: **No**, not unless you can find a USB to TTL cable which will act as a HID device (the cable in itself is a device), which is unlikely.

Comment: Does the RPi3 have the function that is possibly required? or am I still barking out of my legal?

Comment: No.  I should qualify that though: You could do this via the TTL cable (or network) depending on what you can do with the other computer.  If you want the deck to just plug in and work with anything (which a Pi Zero serving as a HID should), then you are out-of-luck.  However, if you can write code on the other side to serve as a HID, or perform whatever macro functions you want, then it's possible -- but you'll have to investigate that based on what OS you want to target.